# Backing up an iOS Wireless Distribution via iTunes

Tags: ios, backup, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution

We are successfully deploying all of our applications via In-house Distribution (Wireless OTA download via Enterprise Profile). Our most recent finding shows that applications distributed wirelessly do not show up in iTunes when the device is plugged in and synchronized.

This concerns me as there is no known way to backup the application data when it is installed OTA.

Are there any known workarounds to allow OTA applications to sync with iTunes?

Comment: I don't think you can make iTunes backup non-AppStore apps, although your data will be backed up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120436/does-itunes-backup-and-restore-works-for-ios-app-deployed-via-ota/20135100#20135100